# Prove discrete inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove the following inequality for each natural $n$:
$$(n+1)^{n-1} \leq n^n$$
In fact I am not sure if it is true, but at least for $n\leq 4$ it holds true. I tried induction, but with no success.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: We have $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\lt 3$. So lots of slack!

Comment: See an inductive [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/716097/85660) for a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For $n > 0$, the inequality is equivalent to

$$\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^{n-1} \leqslant n.$$